# Could we apply L'hospital rule to the following function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital, analytic-functions

Let us think   ${s}$ is complex values as ${s=a+ib}$
And see that with  $x_0=\pi$     with   $u>1$  as  $u\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\sin(x_0+\frac{s}{u})\neq0$$

Now, could we apply L'hospital rule to the following function? Why ?

> $$\lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{\sin 2(x_0+\frac{s}{u})}{\sin(x_0+\frac{s}{u})}   $$

Because we cannot apply L'hospital rule to the following one:

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{(x+x^2e^{i/x^2})}=1   $$

Comment: What is that symbol after the $x$. Please use proper mathjax instead of symbols that don't render properly in all devices

Comment: which one ? I did not understand.

Comment: Use `$\pi$` to render $\pi$, or `$\in$` to render $\in$, and `$x_0$` for $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital requires the mean value theorem which holds in general only for real valued functions defined on real intervals; now for complex valued functions one can sometimes come up with something that is working using Taylor series.

However the second example is oscillating badly which is reflected in the derivative so it's easy to see that any useful analogue of MVT doesn't hold; in other words if $f(x)=x+x^2e^{i/x^2}$ then $f(x)-f(0)=f(x)$ is not in general $xf'(t_x)$ for any $|t_x| \to 0$

For the first example you can argue as follows: $$\lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{\sin 2(x_0+\frac{s}{u})}{\sin(x_0+\frac{s}{u})}=\lim_{v \to 0}\frac{\sin 2(x_0+sv)}{\sin(x_0+sv)}$$ and using the Taylor series we have $\sin 2(x_0+sv)=2sv \cos 2(x_0+c(v)), c(v) \to 0, v \to 0$ and same for denominator.

So in general applying L'Hopital outside its original formulation (real functions on real intervals) requires looking at the specific case and arguing by its properties.

Comment: Thus, you say we can apply  L'Hopital's Rule  to first trigonometric function. I have also checked its limit with a normal way and with L'Hopital  _(derivative with respect to the parameter $u$ )_,   I got the same results.
    But the second one, no success.  Because I have found the limit  of  $\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)$  as  indeterminate  _(which $f(x)=x+x^2e^{i/x^2}$)_.

Comment: You say  **"So in general applying L'Hopital outside its original formulation _(real functions on real intervals)_ requires looking at the specific case and arguing by its properties"**.  Let me add also  " L'Hopital's Rule concerning analytic functions of a complex variable".                                                                                                           
 Now, can we say definitely  as   **"it can also  work for complex functions of a real variable by  looking at the specific case and arguing by its properties"**  ?

Comment: It means we can apply or not apply  L'Hopital for complex functions of a real variable, as depending the situation.

Comment: I think your comments are missing the point a bit; L'Hopital is an elementary technique introduced just after differentiability and MVT in the real analysis context, so very early in the subject; if you go to real analytic functions in 1 variable or complex analytic function in 2, the result is trivial but I wouldn't call it L'Hopital anymore - so the question is in-between where there is some smoothness (not analyticity), a function in the plane or a complex one on the line and then as noted as long as you can still do Taylor series up to some order, you still can try and see if it works

Comment: that was the point of my discussion about the first example, because one can just expand in Taylor series, cancel etc but that is not L'Hopital anymore imho; so to preserve the "spirit" of L'Hopital, you try and write $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=xf'(t_x)$ if possible but in general it is hopeless to find $t_x \in [0,x]$ for the complex case, so one tries and find just $t_x$ so $f'(t_x) \to f'(0)$; if you can this with both numerator and denominator, then you indeed can say that the limit if $f'(0)/g'(0)$ in the spirit of L'Hopital